# Laravel Method [hasMany] does not exist

Tags: laravel

I have 2 controllers and models:

1. User Controller & Model
2. Hero Controller & Model

Each user can have unlimited heroes - it means that the relationship between them is **one to many**.

In my UserController I created the following method:

```
/**
     * Get the heroes of the user.
     */
    public function heroes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Hero::Class);
    }
```

while in my HeroController I created this method:

```
/**
 * Get the user that owns the hero.
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class)
}
```

Added this to my routes file:

```
Route::get('userHeroes', 'UserController@heroes');
```

and it returns this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Method [hasMany] does not exist.","status_code":500}}
```

What could have gone wrong.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **controller** is just a delegate between the request and the return data - you tell it that you want something, it figures out what you want, and then it calls the appropriate places to get something to return.

The `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()` methods, on the other hand, are logic specifically related to the `Hero` and `User` **models**, on the other hand.

What you need is to move the `heroes()` method to your `User` model, because a user can have many heroes. Also need the `user()` method to your `Hero` model, because a hero belongs to a user.

Then you put an **action** call in a controller. Let's say, for instance, that you have a `UserController` which has an `getHeroes()` method. That might look like this:

```
public function getHeroes() {
    $user = auth()->user();
    $heroes = $user->heroes;
    return $heroes;
}
```

And that will format it to JSON. Just an example.

But you might want to read a tutorial or two about this, since it's fairly basic stuff and it's good to get a good handle on early on. Please don't take that the wrong way - we're happy to help if you run into problems, I just think you might need a stronger foundation. The screencasts at Laracasts are highly recommended for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

it must be declared in models,  not in controllers,  hasMany()  is a method in eloquent models.

Answer (score 0):

hasMany and belongsTo methods are eloquent class methods.
And we inherit eloquent in our model so that we can use the eloquent methods functionality.

In order to use the relation, you have to define the relation method in respective model class and then you can call from controller.

Please refer the documentation [Eloquent relationship documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

Hope i have cleared your doubt.

Thanks